# Rails4 "status":"422","error":"Unprocessable Entity"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I want to add some data from the mobile app to my rails app using Json, It working fine, if I use the GET method but when I set it with POST method it give error "status":"422","error":"Unprocessable Entity".

The route is

```
resources :photomsgs, :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

My Controller is

```
def create
  @photomsg = Photomsg.new(photo_params)

 respond_to do |format|
  if @photomsg.save
    format.json { render json: @photomsg, status: :created }
    format.xml { render xml: @photomsg, status: :created }
  else
    format.json { render json: @photomsg.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.xml { render xml: @photomsg.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end 

  def photo_params
    params.require(:photomsg).permit(:title, :physician, :patient)
  end
```

I am using this Json url - http://infinite-depths-5848.herokuapp.com/photomsgs

Comment: It just means that the new model couldn't be saved. Try to check that the model is valid before saving, and that all the photo_params are present.

Comment: Did you check my Json url, is correct for create method? http://infinite-depths-5848.herokuapp.com/photomsgs

Answer (score 6):

This post has been a while, but I stumbled over it today because I had similar error whilst doing a post to my json endpoint. I am going to post the solution here to help someone else in the future.

The error in the logs when this happens is  ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken....

To resolved this, I added:

> skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: :json_request?

right at the top of the controller, and defined the json_request method as follows:

> protected
>
> def json_request?
>       request.format.json?
>    end

Answer (score 4):

As said by @joe-van-dyk it looks like some kind of validation error.

Proceed this way, use byebug to debug the code and look for error messages on the model.

```
def create
  @photomsg = Photomsg.new(photo_params)

 respond_to do |format|
  if @photomsg.save
    format.json { render json: @photomsg, status: :created }
    format.xml { render xml: @photomsg, status: :created }
  else
    byebug
    # => @photomsg.errors.messages
    format.json { render json: @photomsg.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.xml { render xml: @photomsg.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end 

  def photo_params
    params.require(:photomsg).permit(:title, :physician, :patient)
  end
```

Comment: It working fine it I submit the data from the rails web page (Form), But when I send the data from Iphon via Json on http://infinite-depths-5848.herokuapp.com/photomsgs using post method It give error.

Comment: Your JSON isn't formatted correctly. Maybe you aren't using the right key names.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Photomsg model. I got the same error when I was using ActiveRecord association for a table that does not exist(may be a typo).

For example consider the following tables
[image]

And the following model code

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :author
end
```

Notice in the Post model I am referencing to a Author model but the posts  table does not have author_id column. When you try to create entries using the Post model rails throws the error "422 Unprocessable Entity". Just removing the belongs_to association that does not exist should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Send User auth token as header format to web service `httppost.setHeader("Authorization:", token);`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was happening for AJAX calls from rails. I included this in my `application.js` `document.ready` function to resolve the issue.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers:
            { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to csrf token. csrf token is mainly used to protect invalid form submission so that user will not able to submit form data from outside your rails application.

There are two ways to solve this issue.

Option 1: Remove csrf validation from current controller.

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

Adding above code in your controller will skip csrf check in your controller. But it's not recommended as anyone will be able to submit data event from outside your rails application if you are using this option make sure you add more validation.

Option 2: Add CSRF token in your request.
Another option to solve this issue is you can add csrf token on your custom form or to your ajax request.

Step:1 If you are not using any layout you can simply add csrf in your form using below code. If you are using layout make sure to check head Rails by default add csrf in head.

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

this code will add csrf token if you are not using layout.

Step:2 In your ajax request add below code.

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "post", 
       beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
       url: "/form_submit/<%= @form.id %>" ,
       data: form_data, 
       success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
          console.log("this is success");
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

       }
     });
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your validations and make sure that the data you are posting meets those validations.

Comment: I am never used any kind of validation in my model my model is look like: class Photomsg < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :photomsg, :image_data, :image
 
end